# Is there a tag for building loan contracts?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

Is there a tag for building loan contracts, or under which tag a question on that topic should be asked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just tag the question with the [loans](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loans) tag, as well as the country tag for the country that you are located in.  If there are enough questions specific to building loans in the future that necessitates a tag for it, someone will create it.